# Java Matrix Transpose - in pairs

Tags: java, matrix, transpose

I need to transpose the numbers in my nXn square matrix diagonally,  like you do in a regular transpose, only in pairs and from 2nd place to n place.

for example:

```
int[][] matrix1 =  {{11,12,13,14},
                   {15,16,17,18},
                   {19,20,21,22},
                   {23,24,25,26}} ;

   int[][] result= {{11, 12, 15, 16}, 
                   {13, 14, 17, 18}, 
                   {19, 20, 23, 24}, 
                   {21, 22, 25, 26}} ;
```

please note that the last 2 numbers switch with the first 2 of the next row, should there have been 6 numbers, the last 2 would have switched with the middle  2 and so on.

**The code must start with:**

```
public static int[][] blocks (int[][] matrix, int sqrtN)
```

**previously** for my regular transpose I used:

```
  public static int[][] columns (int[][] matrix) {   

      int m = matrix.length;                                                                               
      int n = matrix[0].length;                                                                            

      int[][] columns = new int[n][m];                                                                     

      for (int x = 0; x < n; x++) {                                                                        
          for (int y = 0; y < m; y++) {                                                                    
              columns[x][y] = matrix[y][x];                                                                
          }                                                                                                
      }                                                                                                    

      return columns;                                                                                      
  }
```

EDIT : the specific instructions were:

n has to have to have a square " the function receives a matrix sqrN^2XsqrN^2, the number sqrN represents the size of all the block. its output must be a 2D array that its numbers are the matrix blocks organized from left to right, and up until down."

Comment: Is it given that **n** is even? If not, what should the output be for n=5?

Comment: I think n should be a divisor of m and n.

Comment: BTW `for (int x = 0; x < n; x+1)` should be `for (int x = 0; x < n; x++)`

Comment: to be specific, n has to have to have a square
" the function receives a matrix sqrN^2XsqrN^2, the number sqrN represents the size of all the block. its output must be a 2D array that its numbers are the matrix blocks organized from left to right, and up until down."

Comment: Can you give an example to what should be the result for a 9x9 matrix?